# Where can I find summary of the first three books of "A Song of Ice and Fire"?

Tags: a-song-of-ice-and-fire

I just started reading the fourth book in the series *A Song of Ice and Fire*. Since it is 1.5 years since I finished the third book, I'm pretty confused. Can I read a summary of the earlier books somewhere without spoiling the books that I haven't read yet?

Comment: I'm sure the ASOIAF wiki has good synopsis pages for each of the books

Comment: Yes. So does Wikipedia.

Comment: I can't see how even a basic summary of events could be written to both make sense and also not spoil anything. Suppose it left out the death of any character who has died. Most of them are important enough that you would keep reading the summary past the skipped death and instantly wonder why the summarized events no longer mention a very important character who would be central to those events. You would have to guess the character died and that would be "spoiled" for you. So don't expect to find anything useful that is also spoiler-free.

Comment: I think he wanted a summary of the books he has read, without any details about the book he is now reading.   So the "non-spoiler" description would be for the 4th book.

Comment: @ToddWilcox if I understand the question correct he doesn't want any spoilers of book 4 and 5 in those summaries. But then again, why would any summary of books 1-3 have spoilers of 4 and 5? The question might be a bit confusing.

Comment: Read the books again. It will not be time wasted, as there are many hints and secrets spread out, especially in the first 3 books.

Comment: Hold on, you haven't read books 1 and 2, yet you've read book 3 and are now on book 4? Why on earth would you do that? And what's wrong with reading the whole series from start to finish? I suggest you go back, read books 1 and 2 (which btw contain some pretty critical information), then continue the series.

Comment: I can also suggest [this hilarious review](http://blogoficeandfire.blogspot.com.au/2009/05/introduction.html) of the chapters from the first couple of books (might contain spoilers though).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Personally I would suggest reading the Chapter Summaries on A Wiki of Ice and Fire here:

http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Chapters#A_Game_of_Thrones

It gives a relatively short summary on a per chapter basis. The downside is that everything together is still a lot of text to read, but I think it might be worth it. At least it's a lot faster than reading the entire books again.

Comment: Thank you. I have already read the wiki and can begin book four without getting TOO confused.